# Hibernate using Programmatic Configuration, starting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hbm2ddl, sessionfactory

I am configuration my hibernate sessionfactory programmatically:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", myUrl);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", myUser);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", myPass);

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

**But problem, is that these properties are loaded only, when using hibernate operation from dao.**

```
protected void startOperation() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
}
```

Therefore, when my application boots up, then hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto doesn't seem to work. Can I somehow force hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to start in my program or any other solution?

**Suggetions or other options, thoughts?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto or used

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

Using configuration file like **hibernate.properties** or **hibernate.cfg.xml** is more preferred way to set your setting.

Comment: `Configuration configuration = new Configuration();`  should load my existing hibernate.cfg.xml, which I have and there is line : `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `new Configuration()` should load all the properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

It seems that your  `SessionFactory` is configured to be lazy initialized which only be built when  `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` is called.

If it is a console program , simple call  `SessionFactory.buildSessionFactory()` in the main method

If it is a web application , you  can use [ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) or  Spring  to force the `SessionFactory.buildSessionFactory()` to be executed during the server starts.